# Uniqueness of spectral decomposition

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite, projection-matrices

Consider the spectral decomposition of a hermitian positive semi-definite matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$:

$$A = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i P_i, $$

where $\lambda_i >0$ are the distinct non-zero eigenvalues and $P_i\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are projectors onto the corresponding eigenspaces. If $Q_i\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are arbitrary positive semi-definite matrices with $trQ_i = trP_i$ for each $i$ such that $A= \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i Q_i$, can one conclude that $Q_i=P_i$ for each $i$ ?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

No. E.g.
$$
2\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}
+3\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1}
=\pmatrix{2&0\\ 0&3}
=2\pmatrix{\frac12&0\\ 0&\frac12}
+3\pmatrix{\frac13&0\\ 0&\frac23}.
$$